# Is there a way in Java Spring boot where I can use a single kafka queue for different Java object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to use a single kafka queue for different Java objects. How can I achieve that?

PS: One of the way is to convert the JavaObject to JSON string and on receiving end convert it to desired object and if this conversion operation fails we can handle it gracefully. But I think its not a good solution.

Comment: Why do you think it is not a good solution?

Comment: It is a good solution as far as I can see, and in your Spring Listener you can then use overloaded methods for the different types which keeps your code nice and clean

Comment: I was just hoping that there might be some Spring way to cleanly handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add header to kafka message while sending the msg & based on header value you can cast it to desired Object while receiving it..

Answer (score 0):

You might be use a custom `BatchToRecordAdapter` to call the record level listener, and set some flag in the message from batch to signal that it is the last

See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions-batch)